# Searching for two papers of H.Leland with regards to capital structure

Tags: modeling, research, capital-structure, papers

I am searching for two papers of H. Leland which I assume previously were online, as many published papers have cited them.

The first work (Lecture notes) extends the Leland(1994a) model by accounting for liquidity costs of debt. However, the link provided in the presentation  http://people.bu.edu/dhackbar/HL-2017.pdf is broken.

The second work is the working paper of Leland (1994b) which is missing, even thought it is listed on Ideas.

The titles of these are:

1. **Leland, H. E. (2006). Structural models in corporate Finance: A new structural model. Princeton lecture series in Finance: Lecture
   2, University of California, Berkeley.**
2. **Leland, H. E. (1994a). Bond prices, yield spreads, and optimal capital structure with default risk. Working paper no. 240, IBER,
       University of California, Berkeley.**

Would be pleased if anyone knows a source or archive that provides them

Comment: These slides may be the lecture notes https://www2.ulb.ac.be/cours/solvay/farber/Ofin/Leland%20Princeton%20LECTURE1.pdf .

Comment: I think it is the same series of lectures. But the lecture 2 extends the Leland (1994a) , allowing for liquidity shocks